# Quality of a solution in mathematics

Tags: secondary-education, problem-solving

*How can you determine a quality of a solution for a mathematics problem in general ?* 
If you try to explain too much then solution becomes bit longer and it takes time to go through causing less interest to ones who know the subject sometimes answer may look like a lesson. You can avoid doing similar simplifications and sometimes you can use symmetry to minimize simplifications to keep your answers short. What about using figures to explain the issue ,what else you can suggest and what you would think as the limitations?

Comment: The solution should be appropriate for the audience.

Comment: In what context?  Are you writing a solution to be graded by an instructor or TA?  or are you an instructor or TA trying explain the solution of a problem to a student?  or are you writing a paper for a journal?  a research journal?  expository journal? teaching journal?  "Quality" is not one thing---it depends immensely on the intended audience and the context of the solution.

Comment: @XanderHenderson as we know at a particular exam there are standards and a syllabus but when you engaging in a general platform such as stack exchange according to your views you can expect upvotes and downvotes for the same answer.

Comment: @JanakaRodrigo I am not sure that you have answered my question.  Against what standard are you trying to judge the quality of a solution to a problem?  Who is the target audience?

Comment: Regarding **Target Audience**: Years ago doing an undergraduate lab to determine the mass of an electron, I dutifully ran the experiment many times and averaged the results. My physics advisor asked me, "*How do you justify taking the average?*" Thrown for a loop, I decided that since it was a constant maybe I should do a *Least Squares Fit* to a constant. After much effort and several pages of deriving from first principles I found that it boiled down to the definition of *Average*. My advisor accepted it!